# Why VBA Excel shows Error 91 for a definied variable?

Tags: excel, vba

As new coding maybe this question may be silly, but when I try to run this code, it keeps showing an Error 91 highlighting this line

```
'Get the number from the specified element on the page
number = html.getElementsByClassName("arial_14 redFont").Item(0).innerText
```

As I already identified *number* at the beginning, I have no idea why it keeps showing the variable wasn't defined.

```
Sub Get_Housing_Starts_From_Investing()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim number As Variant

' Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOzHacoP-u4

' Remember to activate References: Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft XML, v6.0, Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation

' Website to go to
website = "https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/housing-starts-151"

' Create the object that will make the website request
Set request = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

' Where to go and how to go there - don´t need to change it
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier
html.body.innerHTML = response

    'Get the number from the specified element on the page
    number = html.getElementsByClassName("arial_14 redFont").Item(0).innerText

' Output the number into a message box
MsgBox number

End Sub
```

Comment: That probably means that `getElementsByClassName("arial_14 redFont")` didn't return any object and therfore `Item(0)` does not exist. And if you `Debug.Print response` you can read *"You don't have permission to access /economic-calendar/housing-starts-151 on this server."*

Comment: But I can access this webpage with Chrome. Is it some limitation from Investing.com?

Comment: many websites do not allow automatic/script data extraction and try to prevent that. Or the data is loaded with JavaScript (which does only run in the browser).  Check if the website has an official API and use that instead.